# Kotlin buildscript not using my custom maven repo

Tags: gradle, kotlin, groovy

Groovy build script

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'custom_url'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
        classpath 'org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.7.2'
        classpath 'org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.7'
    }
}
```

This worked fine, I then converted it to the below Kotlin script.

Kotlin

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url = uri("custom_url") }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9")
        classpath("org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.7.2")
        classpath("org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.7")
    }
}
```

I now get this error -

```
Could not resolve commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.pom'
```

As you can see, it's trying to use `plugins.gradle.org` to get commons-codec, but it should get it from `custom_url` ... any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: The notation looks correct. Are you sure you are editing the right file? Or that it is saved properly prior to execution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are applying a Gradle plugin using the `plugins { ... }` block, then, with Gradle Kotlin DSL, for Gradle to be able to resolve the plugin from your custom repository, you need to add the repository to `settings.gradle.kts` as follows:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven("custom_url")
        gradlePluginPortal() // add this line or Gradle won't lookup the plugin portal!
    }
}
```

This is how Gradle resolves plugins applied with the `plugins { ... }` syntax.

See: [Custom Plugin Repositories](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:custom_plugin_repositories) in the Gradle docs.

Comment: Is it possible to do this outside of `settings.gradle`? We are trying to avoid using any files but `build.gradle.kts`